# Question about class initialization in c++

Tags: c++, oop, c++17

I am learning c++ and I found something that puzzles me, and it's about the initialization of data members in a class.

Given this example:

```
class son
{
public:
    son(){
        std::cout << "constructing class son" << std::endl;
    }
};

class father
{
public:
    father(){
        std::cout << "constructing class father" << std::endl;
    }

private: 
    son s;
};

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ){
    father f; 
}
```

The output is:

```
constructing class son
constructing class father
```

I don't understant why the class `son` is initialized. It is supposed that the declaration in `father` is a declaration, and must be provided a proper initialization in the constructor of
`father()` to initialize, but it appears that it is not needed in the case of class. Is that true?

Comment: @NathanPierson Your comment is an answer.

Comment: thanks, that matches with the observed behaviour. And yes, your comment is definitely an answer, please post it as answer.

Comment: Well, @JerryJeremiah, that's obviously a solution, but I was wondering why c++ behaves like that. I was expecting that either all is have to be initialized in the constructor or all is default-initialized, but it appears that it's a mix: if something is not initialized in the constructor, it's default-initialized.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [cppreference's description](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) of constructors, especially the section on member initializer lists.

> Before the compound statement that forms the function body of the constructor begins executing, initialization of all direct bases, virtual bases, and non-static data members is finished. Member initializer list is the place where non-default initialization of these objects can be specified.

> Initialization order
> The order of member initializers in the list is irrelevant: the actual order of initialization is as follows:
>
> 1. If the constructor is for the most-derived class, virtual bases are initialized in the order in which they appear in depth-first left-to-right traversal of the base class declarations (left-to-right refers to the appearance in base-specifier lists)
> 2. Then, direct bases are initialized in left-to-right order as they appear in this class's base-specifier list
> 3. Then, non-static data member are initialized in order of declaration in the class definition.
> 4. Finally, the body of the constructor is executed

In this case we're really only looking at lines 3 and 4 since there's no inheritance.

The key takeaway is that every member variable is initialized before the body of the constructor is entered, either default-initialized or according to the values in the member initializer list. Since `father::father` doesn't have one, it default-initializes `s`.

Answer (score 1):

To create an object of the class `father` all its data members (sub-objects) must be created. So the object `s` (data member of the type `son` of the class `father`) is created calling the default constructor of the class `son`.

After all sub-objects of the object of the class father have been created the body of the constructor `father` gets the control. That is the body of the constructor of the class `father` deals with already created data members of the object of the type `father`.